How can I create new accounts and interact with the blockchain using Ganache (or other testnets)?
I am developing an Android app with kotlin and I want to create new accounts in the blockchain. I am using Ganache as a testnet. I am creating a new Bip32ECKeyPair for every user in the app and I want to use this keyPair to create a new account in the blockchain. Then, I want to deploy a Smart Contract for each of the users, and use their accounts to interact with said Smart Contract.
The issue I'm facing with Ganache is that, although I can send funds from any of the pre-created accounts to my programmatically newly created accounts, if I try to deploy the contract or interact with the blockchain I get the following error: Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error processing transaction request: sender account not recognized.
I've read other entries in this forum and other webpages and apparently, there is no way to add new accounts to Ganache. I would really appreciate any help, both providing a solution or an alternative to this testnet.

This might help: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/94723/create-new-account-in-ganache.

Not really. I am changing to Sepolia testnet.
